# Should I add sand or more crushed limestone crush to raise paver gravel base 1/4"?

Tags: patio, pavers

I am building a 14' by 20' concrete paver patio.  I have used a 17" retaining wall to raise the left side to be level with the right side.  I have mechanically compacted approx. 8" of 3/4" limestone with fines with a 2% slope away from the house.  My intention is to place the edging bricks (bottom of the slope opposite the house) directly on the top of the retaining wall.  Through internet research, I have found that approx. 3/8" of the 1" bedding sand will either compact or push up in between the pavers "locking" them in place.  My intention was to have 5/8" sand below the top of the retaining wall so that during final compaction of the pavers will match the top of the retaining wall as close as possible.  Unfortunately, after all compaction was complete and the compactor rental returned, I realize I had 7/8" below the top of the retaining wall, a 1/4" too deep.

- First question --> confirmation that 3/8" of the 1" bedding sand will either compact or push up in between the pavers?

If true and understanding many articles state that more than 1" of bedding sand can be an issue, however with only adding a 1/4" would either of the following alternatives provide acceptable results?

- Compact a 1/4” layer of sand under the 1” uncompacted bedding layer
- Use a 1 & 1/4” uncompacted bedding layer?

If neither alternative would give acceptable results then I will work to add more crushed lime stone to make up the 1/4".

Thanks in advance for the advice and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manufacturer of the pavers I will be using has advised to compact a 1/4” layer of sand under the 1” uncompacted bedding layer.

They have also confirmed that 3/8" of the 1" bedding sand will either compact or push up in between the pavers.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the mfgr answer. Be sure to click the check mark as soon as the system will allow it.